# Django app can not find json file in the same directory

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

My json file is in the same directory of view.py file.
However, when I open the html in browser, the IO error happens.
When I run view.py through pycharm, it works fine.
The JSon file is a database configuretion file. I want to display some data from the databse in that case I need to connect to database first.

Comment: Copy paste the code to read the json file from your view.py file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information provided, it is really hard to give you a good answer.
Howevr, I assume, that you run your view in PyCharm by actually running views.py instead of using the runserver command? In this case, the execution directory is the folder of your app and a relative path to the JSON file can be resolved.

As soon as you run a development or real server and access the view in the browser using its URL, the execution directory is the firectory of the manage.py file (the root folder of your project). If you just access the name of your JSON file, then it cannot be found, since you are searching it in the wrong folder.

What are you using the JSON file for? If it should be available in the web borwser as well (as a resource for e.g. JavaScript), then you may want to put it into the static folder of your app or project (remember to run manage.py collectstatic then). In this case, the STATIC_ROOT would be defined in settings.py and you could resolve the path from there (using `os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "path to json file")` )

Comment: Thanks a lot and I think you solved my problem. When I put the json file in the directory of manage.py, the browser can find the json file. But when I put it under directory of app, the IO error happens. Thanks a lot for your explicit answer

Comment: I am glad that worked @SparrowJack.
If your problem is solved in the end, it would be great, if you could mark my answer as the solution.

Comment: I am glad that worked @SparrowJack.
If your problem is solved in the end, it would be great, if you could mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to see the JSON file via browser, you need to put it in the static folder.